# Understanding C++ Postfix Increment Operator Behavior in Assignment: Unexpected Results with obj1++ = obj2;

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue, post-increment

I'm currently reading the Deitel C++ book, and it mentioned the behavior of the postfix increment operator, stating that it typically returns a temporary object containing the original value before the increment, and C++ treats such objects as rvalues. The book also mentions that rvalues cannot be used on the left side of an assignment. On the other hand, the prefix increment operator is said to return the actual incremented object with its new value, allowing it to be used as an lvalue.

The text from the book:

> [...] the postfix increment operator typically returns a temporary object that contains the original value of the object before the increment occurred. C++ treats such objects as rvalues, which cannot be used on the left side of an assignment. The prefix increment operator returns the actual incremented object with its new value. Such
> an object can be used as an lvalue in a continuing expression.

To test this, I wrote a simple C++ program using a Counter class with overloaded prefix and postfix increment operators. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Counter {
private:
    int count;

public:
    Counter(int initialCount = 0) : count(initialCount) {}

    Counter& operator++() {
        ++count;
        return *this;
    }

    Counter operator++(int) {
        Counter temp(*this);
        ++count;
        return temp;
    }

    void display() const {
        std::cout << "Count: " << count << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Counter obj1(5);
    Counter obj2(10);

    ++obj1 = obj2;
    std::cout << "After ++obj1 = obj2; we get: " << std::endl;
    obj1.display();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    obj1++ = obj2;
    std::cout << "After obj1++ = obj2; we get: " << std::endl;
    obj1.display();

    return 0;
}
```

But the consistent output on different compilers is:

```
After ++obj1 = obj2; we get: 
Count: 10

After obj1++ = obj2; we get: 
Count: 11
```

My question is: In the statement `obj1++ = obj2;`, are we not using `obj1++` as an lvalue? According to the book, this should not be possible. Can someone explain this behavior and clarify the concept of rvalues and lvalues in this context?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from assigning to an rvalue of class type.

Comment: @MilesBudnek but the book says we can't. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't assign to prvalues of primitive types, that limitation doesn't apply to class types.

Comment: @Osmium yes, you are missing something - either the book is just plain wrong, or you are misunderstanding what it is telling you. Either way, Miles is correct - you CAN assign to an rvalue that is of a class type. [Demo](https://ideone.com/HBmG46)

Comment: *the Deitel C++ book*  There are several Deitel C++ books.  Which one?  Which chapter?  Which page?

Comment: @Eljay Page 728, first paragraph, Chapter 18 Operator Overloading; Class string, Book: C How to Program, 8th edition.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is clear from your program that the book is wrong (I have added the text of the book in the post) and I am grateful to you.

Comment: @Eljay "*you can disallow assigning to the temporary by providing the method...*" - no that doesn't work, as demonstrated in my earlier demo. What does work is providing `Counter& operator=(Counter const&) && = delete;` instead. [Demo](https://ideone.com/g3wCo8)

Comment: @Osmium - You can also look at this from a different angle: In a real program you will never, ever get the idea to increment a variable and then **also** assign it a new value at the same time. Because Why would you?! So *in practice* you don't have a problem, and can archive this under the "Never happens" category.

Comment: @BoP Yes, this problem indeed belongs to "never happens" category.